# Error: Assembly manifest definition does not match assembly reference, in Analysis Services Custom Script

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Currently my custom script made in Analysis Services gives me the following error when executing it:
`Version=7.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' : Assembly manifest definition does not match assembly reference. (Exception in HRESULT: 0x80131040)`, that exception is given to me in the next part of my program `in ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows() en UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap) en Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)`, On the other hand, all the logic of the code is fine, finally, in the references part there is the respective reference to **System.Text.Json in its version 8.0.0.0** and in the GAC the DLL library was correctly added with this respective version, the problem lies in the DtsDebugHost.exe.config file since it has the following reference `<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="7.0.0.3"/> <codeBase version = "7.0.0.3" href = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\..\..\MSBuild\Current\Bin\System.Text.Json.dll" /> </dependentAssembly>`, Therefore, when I manually edit this file and set it to 8.0.0.0, and recompile the solution, this file is automatically modified and the reference to the library version 7.0.0.3 is reinstated again.

I tried the things that were mentioned before, and none worked.

Answer (score -1):

Simply reinstall Integration Services and the reference in **DtsDebugHost.exe.config** file got correct!.